# Token Revocation in new Spring Authorization Server is not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

After revoking token with **/oauth2/revoke** I can still use this token to request secured data. Actually as I see revoke endpoint does not doing revocation at all it is just removing some metadata. I thought that revocation should drop token from database or invalidate token to not allow user to make further requests with this token. Could somebody please explain what is the expected behavior of **/oauth2/revoke** request (should token be deleted from DB)?

I tried to use default spring token revocation endpoint and it does not work. After revoking token I can still request secured data with this token.

Comment: Have a look at https://huongdanjava.com/token-revocation-with-spring-authorization-server.html

Comment: You need to add more details and code examples so we can help. Generally, you will need to persist revoked tokens (JWT or Opaque) somewhere, since they can't be revoked otherwise (unlike sessions which are associated with the logged-in users),

Comment: `I can still request secured data` from where, from the authorization server, or from any other server? how would any other server know that the token has been revoked... think about, how would they know? You need to provide a lot more information about the infrastructure, servers, requests etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you use a JWT token they are self contains and respect their own expired timestamps. To prevent this fact just make sure the access token has an expiration time of 30 minutes or less. This way the client will have to refresh it token and it will be denied.